# How to get Google Ad Id in android Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the  google ad id (GAID)in android java but I am getting exeception like:

**androidx.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdNotAvailableException: No compatible AndroidX Advertising ID Provider available.**

**My Code**

```
ListenableFuture<AdvertisingIdInfo> adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext());
    System.out.println("adinfo"+adInfo.toString());
    try {
      String id =   adInfo.get().getId();

      System.out.println("adod"+id);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**And dependienced i added**

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha04'
```

**In Manifest I added**

```
  <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true"/>
```

I have tried many solutions but it is not useful. Please help me out to solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The gaid dependency in androidx seems to be at fault.

Many people (including me) have followed [Google's ad ID documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id#java) and have reported the same issue. Also, Google's documentation on this matter appears outdated since the examplatory code snippet is wrong (e.g. function *addCallback* is missing a parameter).

The solution is to **add this dependency** in your gradle file instead of the ones you mentioned:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'`

You can then **fetch the advertising id** this way:

```
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo;

            try {
                idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
                String advertisingId = idInfo.getId();

                //do sth with the id

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

If you want to use the id only when the user hasn't opted out of personalised ads, you can add this after retrieving the id info:

```
     //if user hasn't opted out of ads in device settings
     if(idInfo.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled()) {
         //do sth with the id
     }
```

Edit: The mentioned Google's documentation actually has a note that encourages you to use the ads identifier library I mentioned:

[image]